# How to get a new access token with additional scope without re-login?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microservices, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am working with Cloudfoundry UAA

I am not sure if it is possible in standard oauth2.
The situation is ->

1. User logs into the app
2. He receives an access_token and refresh_token
3. He can keep on acquiring new access_tokens which has original scopes
4. His access permission changes so new scopes are added for him

Now I need a new access token, without him to log in again.
Is it possible that I can use the same refresh_token and ask for access_token with modified scopes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word no. This would be a **violation** of the user's Trust.
And in case you have not heard, that is a bad thing.

There is an Internet Draft RFC [OAuth 2.0 Incremental Authorization](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wdenniss-oauth-incremental-auth-01) (put forth by Google)
There is some talk about it [here](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20Incremental%20Authorization).

Comment: Thank you @jwilleke for the answer with references. I thought this would be non standard, will not do this in this way.